# Implementing Java Priority Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> {
 private PriorityNode<T> head, tail;
 private int numItems;

 public PriorityQueue(){
  numItems = 0;
  head=null;
  tail=null;
 }


 public void add(int priority, T value){
      PriorityNode<T> newNode = new PriorityNode<T>(priority,value);

      if(numItems == 0){
       head = newNode;
       tail = newNode;
      }
      else{
       head.setNext(newNode);
       head = newNode;
      }



     }

    }
```

Where PriorityNode is defined as:

```
 public class PriorityNode<T> implements Comparable<T> {
     private T value;
     private PriorityNode<T> next;
     private int priority;

     public PriorityNode(int priority,T newValue){
      value = newValue;
      next = null;
      priority = 0;
     }

     public PriorityNode(T newValue){
      value = newValue;
      next = null;
      priority = 0;
     }

     public void setPriority(int priority){
      this.priority = priority;
     }

     public int getPriority(){
      return this.priority;
     }

     public T getValue(){
      return value;
     }

     public PriorityNode<T> getNext(){
      return next;
     }

     public void setNext(PriorityNode<T> nextNode){
      this.next = nextNode;
     }

     public void setValue(T newValue){
      value = newValue;
     }

           @Override
     public int compareTo(int pri) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(this.priority<pri){
           return -1;
        }
        else if(this.priority == pri){
           return 0;
         }
        else{
           return 1;
         }


     }


    }
```

I'm having a lot of difficulty using the Comparator here and implementing a priority queue - please point me in the right direction.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is. What is the 'difficulty'? compile error? unexpected results?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a tree structure to implement a priority queue. Use a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). It is more space-efficient, requires fewer memory allocations, and is O(log(N)) for most operations.

Comment: That's true, but i'm trying to complete this type of implemntation before an examiner springs this on me .

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the implementing of the comparator, implementing the [`Comparator<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or [`Comparable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface requires the `public int compareTo(T o)` method to be overridden.

In the example code given, the `compareTo(T)` method is not overridden (the `compareTo(int)` method is defined, but that is *not* the same method signature), therefore, it will probably lead to a compiler error.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are making it a bit too tough on yourself, a priority queue is efficiently implemented with array-based heaps: simpler and more efficient (read: contiguous memory areas).

Comment: What was that link about?!